# How to combine the left sides of Either objects in fp-ts?

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, either, fp-ts

I have two validation functions for different values that return `Either`. I'd like to throw an exception if one of them has a `left` value and do nothing if both are `right`. I've never used fp-ts before and can't figure out how to properly combine left results. My current solution works but does not feel like i'm using it properly.

```js
import { Either, left, right, isLeft, getOrElse } from 'fp-ts/lib/Either';

function validateMonth( m: Month ): Either<Error, Month> {
   return m.isInRange() ? right(m) : left(new Error('Month must be in range!'));
}

function validateYear( y: Year ): Either<Error, Year> {
   return year.isBefore(2038) ? right(y) : left(new Error('Year must be before 2038!'));
}

function throwingValidator(m: Month, y: Year): void {
 // todo: Refactor to get rid of intermediate variables,
 // combining results of validateMonth and validateYear into a type
 // of Either<Error, Unit>
 const monthResult = validateMonth( month );
 const yearResult = validateYear( year );
 const throwOnError = (e: Error) => { throw e; };
 if ( isLeft( monthResult ) ) { getOrElse(throwOnError)(monthResult); }
 if ( isLeft( yearResult ) ) { getOrElse(throwOnError)(yearResult); }
}
```

I've read the introduction at https://dev.to/gcanti/getting-started-with-fp-ts-either-vs-validation-5eja but that code is exactly the opposite of what I want: I don't care about the input value after the validation and want to return only the first error that occurs.

Comment: `getOrElse` is used to get a result value, but you're not doing anything with its return value - why do you even call it? And especially why call it only when you've already established that it's a `Left` value? That said, throwing exceptions is not really a good practice in functional programming, so it's naturally a bit hard.

Comment: If you don't care about the return value, `Either` is not the right choice for the return type. Or at least, not `Either<Error, Result>` - at best you'd do `Either<Error, Unit>`. (Where in TypeScript, `Unit` is either `void` or `undefined` or `null`).

Comment: I'm misusing `getOrElse` to call a function for the error case. But you're right about exceptions - what I really want to do is capture the `Error` object and return it in a rejected promise. When all values are correct, i want to return a Promise with a specific data structure.

Comment: Well at least you shouldn't need both of `isLeft` and `getOrElse` - one of them would be enough.

Comment: People might also check out this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/array-of-validators-vxgj6?from-embed=&file=/src/arrayOfValidators.ts:110-153

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignoring `throwingValidator` and throwing in general (which kind of defeats the purpose of using `fp-ts` in the first place) and focusing only on this specific request:

> Refactor to get rid of intermediate variables, combining results of validateMonth and validateYear into a type of Either

You are probably looking for:

```
const monthAndYearResult: Either<
  Error,
  { month: Month, year: Year }
> = sequenceS(either)({
  month: validateMonth(month),
  year: validateYear(year)
})
```

"sequence"ing in general requires an instance of `Traversable` (the struct `{ year, month }` in this case) and an instance of `Applicative` (`either` in this case), and the semantics are the ones of aggregating different independent computations together.

If you explicitly want to ignore the result, usually a `_`-suffix alternative is provided to accomplish this, but it isn't as of now in `fp-ts` v2.

To obtain a `Either<Error, void>` you can thus resort to:

```
const result = pipe(
  sequenceS(E.either)({ month: validateMonth(month), year: validateYear(year) }),
  E.map(constVoid)
)
```

---

Note that `sequenceS` is just one of the possible options, you could use `sequenceT` or `array.sequence` to obtain similar results, e.g.:

```
pipe(
  sequenceT(either)([validateMonth(month), validateYear(year)]),
  E.map(constVoid)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for something like

```
const toPromise = fold(e => Promise.reject(e), r => Promise.resolve(r));

Promise.all([
    toPromise(validateMonth(month)),
    toPromise(validateYear(year)),
]).then(([validMonth, validYear]) => {
    return …
});
```

or the more functional way

```
toPromise(ap(ap(of(validMonth => validYear => {
    return …
}), validateMonth(month)), validateYear(year)))
```

You can also do the `Promise.all` with `array.sequence` and the `toPromise` afterwards.

Comment: @bob For some reason I thought that `map` did have the wrong (flipped) signature, and I totally missed `liftA2`.

Comment: @Bergi why introducing `Promise` here?

Comment: @GiovanniGonzaga OP wrote (in a comment) "*When all values are correct, i want to return a Promise with a specific data structure*". Using rejected promises as a return value is easier than throwing.

Comment: I see, I got confused because `Promise`/async is not mentioned in the original question.

Re "rejected promises as a return value is easier than throwing", the equivalent fp-ts encoding would be a `TaskEither` which is a `() => Promise<Either<L, A>>` (lazy because promises being eager break referential transparency)